# GCE Highmem Instance Slow

Tags: performance, centos, google-compute-engine

I am connecting to a CentOS booted from a persistent disk created from [here](https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-6-v20140318). The instance is a n1-standard instance but I'm having some serious performance issues.

I can SSH into the instance just fine, however commands take a long time to run. I tried to just run a simple ping command to google.com and it took 2 minutes and 36 seconds to start the command. The CPU usage is next to none as there isn't really anything going on within the instance except an Apache installation that isn't doing anything yet. My internet connection is just fine, and other instances work just fine. I've even deleted the instance and started over from scratch.

Is there something wrong with the image CentOS is being created from or is this just a problem I'm having? What steps can I take to narrow down the problems?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? I tried to reproduce this myself and was not able to. I used n1-standard-1 and n1-highmem-2 instances with Apache installed (in us-central1-a zone). I pinged google.com and yahoo.com and both were fast, no wait time and 1ms typical 5ms max. Which zone, time, and machine types did you use?

Comment: I'm not having the problem anymore. I looked into it the next day and it seems like there were a few people having problems between 3:00am to 6:00am that morning.